# Selenium WebDriver downloads .msg type on Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, mime-types, firefox-profile

I setup a Firefox Profile to download files on Firefox. This is my code:

```
String mimeTypes = "application/zip,application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-outlook";
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", path);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", mimeTypes);
```

For zip files, it works and the file is saved automatically, without opening the *Download* dialog. But for `.msg` files it doesn't work, the *Download* dialog still appears and the file is not saved.

I've tried the MIME for `.msg` file and I found on the internet as shown in the code above, but it doesn't work.

My questions:

1. What is the correct MIME of `.msg` file type?
2. Is there a way to setPreference for `neverAsk.saveToDisk` to save all types without adding a long list of MIME types?

I am testing with latest FF 60 and Selenium 3.12 and geckoDriver v.0.20.

**EDIT:**

I don't know if this is the reason, but in my test I click to download 2 files one after one, the zip file first and then `.msg` file. I also tried to replaced `.msg` file with `.jpg` and `.pdf` and they have the same problem like with `.msg` file. It seems like setPreference for `neverAsk.saveToDisk` only affects for one MIME type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I went to check all mime types of files being downloaded. Except File1's mime type stays as it is, File2's mime type is somehow changed to `application/domain-of-my-app` regardless to the actual mime type of this file. After adding this new mime type `application/domain-of-my-app` to the list, it works as expected.